# newline space at the top of the file

Tags: bash

I am trying to install automate the process to install all my jobs, but I Have a simple issue. why do I Have a `\n` at the top of my job file ?

```
echo -e "\e[00;33m### Installing jobs #####################################\e[00m"

crontab -l > job
echo -e "* * * * * cd /home/job/job && bash job.sh" >> job
#crontab job
#rm job
```

```sh
* * * * * cd /home/job/job && bash job.sh
```

Comment: I don't know, why do you? Does the file already contain one?

Comment: nope , but it adds . I tried to execute echo in command line , and works perfectly without newline

Comment: Your script just append a line to the current crontab. Possible that your current crontab has empty line ?